# MySQL mysqldump command error(bug in mysql 5.5)

Tags: sql, database, mysql

I am working on exporting a table from my server DB which is about few thousand rows and the PHPMyadmin is unable to handle it.So I switched to the **command line option**
But I am running into this error after executing the `mysqldump` command.The error is

`Couldn't execute 'SET OPTION SQL_QUOTE_SHOW_CREATE=1': You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OPTION SQL_QUOTE_SHOW_CREATE=1' at line 1 (1064)`
After doing some search on the same I found this as a [bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=67507) in the mysql version 5.5 not supporting the `SET OPTION` command.
I am running a EC2 instance with centos on it.My mysql version is `5.5.31`(from my phpinfo).

**I would like to know if there is a fix for this as it wont be possible to upgrade the entire database for this error**.
Or if there is any other alternative to do a export or dump,please suggest.

Comment: How about using grep/sed/awk to remove those lines from the dump?

Comment: I believe you're talking about replacing the `SET OPTION` to `SET` right?I rad about it but I am not that good at unix and so refraing from doing so! :P Can you help me with the actual command for it?

Comment: did you need the table structure of just the data? if you just need the data could you use select into and create a file? (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html)

Comment: only Data can do,I will try it! Can I import it back by using `mysql` import feature??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to mysqldump is the SELECT ... INTO form of SELECT, which allows results to be written to a file (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select-into.html).

Some example syntax from the above help page is:

```
SELECT a,b,a+b INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/result.txt'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM test_table;
```

Data can then be loaded back in using LOAD DATA INFILE (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html).

Again the page gives an example:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/test.txt' INTO TABLE test
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  LINES STARTING BY 'xxx';
```

And with a complete worked example pair:

> When you use SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE in tandem with LOAD DATA INFILE
>   to write data from a database into a file and then read the file back
>   into the database later, the field- and line-handling options for both
>   statements must match. Otherwise, LOAD DATA INFILE will not interpret
>   the contents of the file properly. Suppose that you use SELECT ...
>   INTO OUTFILE to write a file with fields delimited by commas:
>
> ```
> SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'data.txt'   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','   
> FROM table2;
> ```
>
> To read the comma-delimited file back in, the correct statement would
>   be:
>
> ```
>  LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.txt' INTO TABLE table2   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
> ```

Comment: `a,b,a+b` refer to the columns right? so I can do a * over there!??

Comment: yup, anything you can do in a normal query.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but something like this:

```
cat yourdumpfile.sql | grep -v "SET OPTION SQL_QUOTE_SHOW_CREATE" | mysql -u user -p -h host databasename
```

This inserts the dump into your database, but removes the lines containing "SET OPTION SQL_QUOTE_SHOW_CREATE". The `-v` means reverting.

Couldn't find the english manual entry for SQL_QUOTE_SHOW_CREATE to link it here, but you don't need this option at all, when your table and database names don't include special characters or something (meaning they don't need to put in quotes).

UPDATE:

```
mysqldump -u user -p -h host database | grep -v "SET OPTION SQL_QUOTE_SHOW_CREATE" > yourdumpfile.sql
```

Then when you insert the dump into database you have to do nothing special.

```
mysql -u user -p -h host database < yourdumpfile.sql
```

Comment: So I should test it something like this `cat yourdumpfile.sql | grep -v "SET OPTION SQL_QUOTE_SHOW_CREATE" | 
mysqldump -u root1 -p -h prod-DB-enpoint my_db tbl_revision` Am I right??

Comment: No, you already have your dumpfile, right? No dumping, just `mysql` so you insert the dump into your database. Updated answer as well.

Comment: I want to export it first and I get the error while exporting as I mentioned in question!

Answer (score 0):

I used quick and dirty hack for this.

1. Download mysql 5.6. (from https://downloads.mariadb.com/archive/signature/p/mysql/f/mysql-5.6.13-linux-glibc2.5-x86_64.tar.gz/v/5.6.13)
2. Untar and use newly downloaded mysqldump.